# Input data for predictions in gbm

Tags: r

I train a model using `gbm(..., data = traindata, ...)` and make predictions using `predict(... newdata = newdata, ...)`.

My question: do traindata and newdata need to have the same format (order and number of variables)?

In the gbm manual, the following is written for predict():

> If object was fit using gbm.fit there will be no Terms component.
>   Therefore, the user has greater responsibility to make sure that
>   newdata is of the same format (order and number of variables) as the
>   one originally used to fit the model.

Is this also true for gbm or only for gbm.fit? Can newdata have a different format than traindata?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your data has a dimension of M*N (M number of sample and N number of variables) if so, then your prediction set needs to have K*N means then number of sample is not important but the number of variables are. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but do the N variables in the prediction set need to have the same order as in the training set (gbm)?

Furthermore, can the prediction set have additional variables compared to the training set? These parameters should obviously be ignored in the prediction.

My question is whether gbm() and predict() recognize the lables of the variables. If so, the order of the variables and additional variables in the prediction set should have no impact on the prediction.

Thanks